# Which type of WiFi router do I need?

Tags: router, wireless-router, modem

The connection which will go into the router is what I currently use into the the laptop's ethernet port. I am confused between ADSL, ADSL2+ and a lot different type of modems/routers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you already have a modem with ADSL input and Ethernet output.
There are 2 options:

- 1. Get a router with ADSL support and replace the current modem. It will be modem and router in the same device. All the ones currently on the market support ADSL2+ and are compatible with ADSL v1.
- 2. Get a normal Ethernet router and connect its WAN to the modem's Ethernet you now have your notebook cable in.

In both situations you will have to configure the new equipment. In the first case, the ADSL account settings will have to be configured on the new ADSL router, additionally to the otherwise normal configurations (DHCP, wireless settings, etc) that should be done on both cases.

Answer (score -1):

You can buy any wireless router and plug the cable you're currently plug into the laptop into the WAN port on that router. You don't need a modem; you already have one if you can plug your laptop in. Go to your preferred online shopping site, search for wireless router and look at the reviews.